# Lee's proof of the Canonical Form Near a Regular Point

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Lee's proof relies on [the flowout theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Book:John_M._Lee/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds) but I want to find a more "from scratch" proof. I am self-studying this, and have not looked elsewhere so if this is trivial or old hat, I will gladly delete it. But please, after getting feedback and a bit of help! Paraphrasing Prof. Lee:

> Let $V$ be a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$; and let $p\in M$ be a regular point of $V.$ There exist smooth coordinates $s_i$ on some neighborhood of $p$ in which $V$ has the co-ordinate representation $\partial s_1.$

The flowout theorem is used to produce a diffeomorphism which is the restriction of the flow to a flow domain. The rest of the proof follows easily. I want to do it like this:

Since $V_p\neq 0,$ it's not hard to show that there are coordinates $p\in (s_1,\cdots,s_n)$ such that $V_p=\partial s_1.$ Let $(U,\varphi)$ be the corresponding chart about $p.$

Now, let $\Phi_t$ be the flow of $V$ and define $F:\varphi(U)\to M$ by  $F(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=\Phi_{x_1}\circ (\varphi^{-1}(0,x_2,\cdots, x_n)),$ so $F(0)=\Phi(0,p)=p.$

I want to show that $dF_0$ is invertible, because then $F^{-1}$ will provide the required coordinates.

Because we have, for an arbitrary test function $f,$

$\ dF_0\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)f=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)_{x_1=0}(f\circ \Phi_{x_1}(\varphi^{-1}(0))=\Phi'(0,p)f=V_pf=\partial s_1f.$

And so now assuming invertibility of $dF_0,$ we get from the inverse function theorem a neighborhood of $p$ such that   $\partial _{s_1}=V.$

If I could show as in the above calculation, that $dF_0$ carries $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$ to $\partial s_i$ for $2\le i\le n,$ that would do it.

edit: using Didier's comment, this follows from

$\ dF_0\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)=d\Phi_{(0,p)}\circ d\varphi^{-1}_0\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)=d\Phi_{(0,p)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i}\right)$

because $\Phi(0,p)=p,$ the identity. So I guess the proof is correct.

Here is the proof that uses flowouts.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more context, e.g. include the theorem that you want to prove, and the theorem that you want to avoid using? Not everybody has the book at hand.

Comment: $\Phi(0,y) = y$ since $\Phi(0,\cdot)$ is the time zero of the flow of a vector field, which is always the identity map. The rest follows easily!

Comment: @Yai0Phah: Yes ok.

Comment: @Didier: yes, I get it now! Thanks.